# Android: Text Colors not changing

Tags: android

I'm writing a quiz application which presents the user with a question and 4 choices. When the user clicks on a choice, the app should change the colour of the correct choice to green and the colour of the incorrect choice to red. It should then wait a second before displaying the next question.

The problem is that it doesn't do the colour changes (except for the last question) and I don't understand why. I know that my `android.os.SystemClock.sleep(1000)` has something to do with it.

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me where I've gone wrong or if I'm going about this an incorrect way. Thanks :)

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    setButtonsEnabled(false);
    int answer = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
    int correct = question.getCorrectAnswer();

    if(answer == correct)
        numCorrect++;
    highlightAnswer(answer,correct,false);
    android.os.SystemClock.sleep(1000);

    MCQuestion next = getRandomQuestion();
    if(next != null) {
        question = next;
        highlightAnswer(answer,correct,true);
        displayQuestion();
        setButtonsEnabled(true);
    }
    else {
        float percentage = 100*(numCorrect/questionsList.size());
        QuizTimeApplication.setScore(percentage);
        Intent scoreIntent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,ScoreActivity.class);
        startActivity(scoreIntent);
    }
}

private void setButtonsEnabled(boolean enable) {
    for(Button b: buttons)
        b.setEnabled(enable);
}

private void highlightAnswer(int answer, int correct, boolean undo) {
    if(undo) {
        for(Button button : buttons) {
            button.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            button.setTextSize(FONT_SIZE_NORMAL);
        }
        return;
    }
    buttons[correct].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    buttons[correct].setTextSize(FONT_SIZE_BIG);
    if(answer!=correct) {
        buttons[answer].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        buttons[answer].setTextSize(FONT_SIZE_BIG);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove all the code after the call highlightAnswer(). Remove the sleep call and the if,else block. If the highlights as you intend then the issue is with the sleep command. Thread sleeps before the updates are put on the screen.

If this is the case you will need to use AsyncTask to do the wait and the callback to show the next question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SystemClock.sleep(1000);
```

will give unexpected behaviour and may not work good for your requirement. It is better you use Handler with a delay like below.

```
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

@Override
public void run()
{
//your code that has to be run after a delay of time. in your case the code after SystemClock.sleep(1000);
},YOUR_DELAY_IN_MILLISECONDS
);
```